# What event is triggered on a text input after using speech recognition in iOS?

Tags: ios, dom-events, speech-to-text, html-input

I'm beginning to think that iOS does not trigger an event when it inserts text from speech recognition into an html input. I've tried listening for:
change, keyup, keydown, blur, focus, paste.

Anyone know the secret?

Answer (score 7):

Found it.  The "input" event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! ❤️ I've been searching for it for a long time!